# Calabash android wrong css element coordinates after drag

Tags: android, scroll, drag, calabash

I am developing a hybrid app for android. It uses a WebView with html.
I write calabash android tests for this program. We have menu items in  and need to scroll them. PerformAction ('scroll_to', 'css', arg1) scrolls another list, not the one we need. I tried to describe scroll using function performAction ('drag', fromX, toX, fromY, toY, steps). But after the scroll we have the wrong element (menu item) coordinates, that's why another options is selected.
Looks like problem when use CordovaWebView.

Comment: Posting some relevant code might help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds similar to other issues where touching and moving an element and animating the same element with a CSS transform, meant that the touch location of the elements no longer matched where the element was on the screen.

Try invalidating the page after the page was scrolled (i.e. list.innerHTML = list.innerHTML).

This is a far from good solution, but should help you figure out if it's similar to this: [Android 4 Chrome hit testing issue on touch events after CSS transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16703157/android-4-chrome-hit-testing-issue-on-touch-events-after-css-transform/17315205#17315205)

Comment: Tried to work around this solution. Used performAction('execute_javascript', "document.getElementById('my_div_id').style.visibility='hiden'") performAction('execute_javascript', "document.getElementById('my_div_id').style.visibility='visible'") This does not solve the problem.